# How do I know the total size of all the videos I've uploaded to Vimeo?

Tags: vimeo

Is there a way to know the total size of my uploaded videos on Vimeo (the sum of the sizes for all videos)?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on Settings->Billing->Cancel Subscription it shows you how much GB of space you used in the pop up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you login with your browser, there is an indication bottom left of the screen, saying: "Total limit: XXX of (whatever your quota is)". Is there any reason why you can't use it?

Comment: But that's the mohtly limit. It's not the overal size of all my videos on my account